# getting unimplemented methods error even though I have implemented them

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6, silhouette

I am getting the following error in my `Play`, `Silhouette`, `Cassandra` application

`class UsersRepository needs to be abstract, since: it has 6 unimplemented members. 
/** As seen from class UsersRepository, the missing signatures are as follows. * For convenience, these are usable as stub implementations. */ // Members declared in com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.repositories.AuthInfoRepository`

`def add[T <: com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.AuthInfo](loginInfo: com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.LoginInfo,authInfo: T): scala.concurrent.Future[T] = ???`

`def find[T <: com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.AuthInfo](loginInfo: com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.LoginInfo)(implicit tag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]): scala.concurrent.Future[Option[T]] = ???`

`def remove[T <: com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.AuthInfo](loginInfo: com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.LoginInfo)(implicit tag: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]): scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = ???`

`def save[T <: com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.AuthInfo](loginInfo: com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.LoginInfo,authInfo: T): scala.concurrent.Future[T] = ???`

`def update[T <: com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.AuthInfo](loginInfo: com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.LoginInfo,authInfo: T): scala.concurrent.Future[T] = ???`

However, in the same file, I have implemented them

```
class UsersRepository(session: Session) 
  extends CassandraRepository[UserKeys,User](session, "users", List("bucket","email")) with UserDao with AuthInfoRepository {

        def find(loginInfo:LoginInfo):Future[Option[PasswordInfo]] = Future {
    ...      }

          def add(loginInfo:LoginInfo, authInfo:PasswordInfo):Future[PasswordInfo] = Future {
       ...
          }

          def update(loginInfo:LoginInfo, authInfo:PasswordInfo):Future[PasswordInfo] = {
add(..)//add returns a Future
    ...}

          def save(loginInfo:LoginInfo, authInfo:PasswordInfo):Future[PasswordInfo] =  {
            add(..)//add returns a Future
}

          def remove(loginInfo:LoginInfo):Future[Unit] = Future{
    ...
          }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please post complete code and don't post the error in code format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you actually didn't override them:

```
def add[T <: AuthInfo](
  loginInfo: LoginInfo,
  authInfo: T
): Future[T]
```

vs

```
def add(
  loginInfo:LoginInfo,
  authInfo: PasswordInfo
):Future[PasswordInfo]
```

The former takes *anything* that can be an instance of `AuthInfo`, the latter a very specific case where it is exactly `PasswordInfo`.

When you mix OOP into it, e.g. upcasting to the parental interface, the specialization might not be actually visibly and compiler will have to use generic (unimplemented) method.

In such cases it is safer to add `override` keyword and be sure that you are actually overriding the `???` implementation.

Comment: Thanks. If you meant that I change `def add(loginInfo:LoginInfo, authInfo:PasswordInfo):Future[PasswordInfo]` to `override def add(loginInfo:LoginInfo, authInfo:PasswordInfo):Future[PasswordInfo]` then unfortunately that didn't work. Also, I could see in IDE the message that `method find overrides nothing`

Comment: That means precisely what I meant: you need to change your signature to `def add[T <: AuthInfo](
  loginInfo: LoginInfo,
  authInfo: T
): Future[T]`. If you handle only `PasswordInfo` case you might consider moving `[T]` on trait/class level, and then implement this trait for a specific `T`.

Comment: I think you answer is correct but I am unable to verify it. `AuthInfoRepository` is already a trait. I am implementing the trait in `UsersRepository` class and I want to implement it specifically for `PasswordInfo` because the `find`, `add` methods use fields specific to `PasswordInfo`. But I am unable to understand how I could do this. As the new code (the one you suggested) uses `T` instead of `PasswordInfo`, I anymore cannot use fields specific to `PasswordInfo` and thus am getting compilation error. How do I "move [T] on trait/class level, and then implement this trait for a specific T"

Comment: I am accepting your answer because it answers that I am not correctly overriding. The issue I am still facing is probably a design issue and thus I have opened another ticket. Could you please take a look a that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014824/unable-to-override-an-abstract-method-of-a-trait