# Unable to override an abstract method of a trait

Tags: scala

I have a trait with an unimplemented method (the trait is from a 3rd party library so I can't change it)

```
scala> trait A {
     |  def B[T](b:T):T
     | }
defined trait A
```

I am trying to extend it and implement the method `B` in it (have tried three ways) but I am getting the following error. My main requirement is that I want to implement `B` for `T` as `Int` (i.e. `B[Int]` and return `b*2`)

```
scala> class C extends A {
     | def B(b:Int):Int = b*2
     | }
<console>:12: error: class C needs to be abstract, since method B in trait A of type [T](b: T)T is not defined
       class C extends A {
             ^

scala> class C extends A {
     | def B[T](b:T):T = b*2 //I know why this doesn't work but how could I implement B[Int]
     | }
<console>:13: error: value * is not a member of type parameter T
       def B[T](b:T):T = b*2
                          ^

scala> class C extends A {
     | override def B(b:Int):Int = b*2
     | }
<console>:12: error: class C needs to be abstract, since method B in trait A of type [T](b: T)T is not defined
       class C extends A {
             ^
<console>:13: error: method B overrides nothing.
Note: the super classes of class C contain the following, non final members named B:
def B[T](b: T): T
       override def B(b:Int):Int = b*2
                    ^

scala>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a concrete class that extends A you need to provide an implementation for all abstract methods in A. So in this case, you need to provide an implementation for

```
def B[T](b: T):T
```

Since `B` is a generic function you need to provide a generic implementation of `B` as well as your specialisation for `Int`.

```
def B[T](b: T): T = b
def B(b: Int): Int = b*2
```

The compiler will use the specialised version of `B` for `Int` values and the generic version for all other values.

### Warning

A previous answer suggests

```
override def B[Int](b: Int): Int = b
```

But in this case the `Int` is a *type parameter* and **not** the `Int` data type, so this is a generic function and is exactly the same as

```
override def B[T](b: T): T = b
```

This provides a concrete implementation of `B` that is the `identity` function. This may or may not be what you want...

Comment: Thanks. It worked. `scala> class C extends A {
     |      def B[T](b:T):T = b
     | def B(b:Int):Int = b*2
     | }
defined class C
scala> new C().B(2)
res2: Int = 4
scala> new C().B("f")
res3: String = f`

Comment: I am wondering, isn't it inconvenient and confusing though that I have to provide both implementations. What is the motive behind this? If I want my code to work only for `Int` and say `Float` then isn't it better that I only provide these two implementations and compiler gives error if I try to use some other data type?

Comment: @ManuChadha The trait `A` is defined to support a method `B` for all data types, and you can't override that because other users of `A` will expect it. The compiler can't do the check you describe at compile time, and doing it at runtime would remove some type safety so better to make the programmer do the check if required.

Answer (score 2):

Original method is supposed to work for arbitrary input type `T`. If you want to implement/override it you also have to support it for all possible input types.

So it's better not to inherit from this trait if you can't support it.

If you do have to do it the only way is do like that:

```
case class C() extends A {
  override def B[T](b: T): T = {
    val res = b.asInstanceOf[Int] * 2
    res.asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}
```

and pray that only int values will be supplied as an input.

Comment: Thanks Simpadjo. I was trying this but I didn't return `res.asInstanceOf[T]`. Thus the code didn't compile. Now I know how to solve the problem this way as well.